# c# .net WinForms - Cursor changes on new Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cursor

I am working on a simple project with multiple transitions between different Forms.

Now after working on my current form for a while I noticed that my cursor changed to [an odd symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HN9RA.png). This phenomenon is limited to my newest form whenever I place the mouse over it.

There are no cursor changes at all in the code, so something else must be influencing it. In the form I am using multiple labels, a picture box and draw a large image using System.Drawing.

Are there any known mistakes that cause this behavior or should I provide the code?

As this is my first question on this site I'd also be open to know if I could improve my questions/tagging. The site tells me to use "text-cursor" instead of "cursor" but that tag appears to be missing, so I'll use the cursor tag instead.

Comment: See `Cursor` property on `Properties` tab. Set it to `Default`.

Comment: Check the `Cursor` property of the form in designer.

Comment: That was incredibly fast, thank you very very much! http://puu.sh/A54xI/3bb6622f2c.png